# Django: Get selected fields from a One2Many relationship

Tags: python, django, models

In Django I have 2 tables in my models: **app_title** and the **auth_user** table. How do I query all rows while returning only the `name` field from app_title and the `username` and `email` fields from the auth_user table? It's basically a One2Many relationship. I can't seem to get it right.

```
class Title(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=2)   # Don't return this field
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you need just
 `titles = Title.objects.all().values('name', 'user__username', 'user__email')`?
 - that give you a queryset with only those fields.
More about [values()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#values).